# Reimplementing Map.fromListWith function

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

I have been trying to reimplement the [`Map.fromListWith`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.2.0.1/docs/Data-Map.html#v:fromListWith) function in Haskell, but I'm running up against an error I don't understand.

Here's my implementation:

```
fromListWith_ :: (a -> a -> a) -> [(k, a)] -> Map.Map k a
fromListWith_ fn = foldl foldfn Map.empty
  where
    foldfn :: (Map.Map k a) -> (k, a) -> Map.Map k a
    foldfn m (key, val) = Map.insertWith fn key val m
```

Here's my error:

```
Lecture8.hs:33:49: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type 'a' with actual type 'a1'
      'a1' is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          foldfn :: forall k1 a1. Map.Map k1 a1 -> (k1, a1) -> Map.Map k1 a1
        at src/Lecture8.hs:32:15
      'a' is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          fromListWith_ :: forall a k.
                           (a -> a -> a) -> [(k, a)] -> Map.Map k a
        at src/Lecture8.hs:29:18
    • In the third argument of 'Map.insertWith', namely 'val'
      In the expression: Map.insertWith fn key val m
      In an equation for 'foldfn':
          foldfn m (key, val) = Map.insertWith fn key val m
    • Relevant bindings include
        val :: a1 (bound at src/Lecture8.hs:33:20)
        m :: Map.Map k1 a1 (bound at src/Lecture8.hs:33:12)
        foldfn :: Map.Map k1 a1 -> (k1, a1) -> Map.Map k1 a1
          (bound at src/Lecture8.hs:33:5)
        fn :: a -> a -> a (bound at src/Lecture8.hs:30:15)
        fromListWith_ :: (a -> a -> a) -> [(k, a)] -> Map.Map k a
          (bound at src/Lecture8.hs:30:1)
```

I have tried removing the type annotation from `foldfn`, which yields a different error:

```
Lecture8.hs:32:26: error:
    • No instance for (Ord k) arising from a use of ‘foldfn’
      Possible fix:
        add (Ord k) to the context of
          the type signature for:
            fromListWith_ :: (a -> a -> a) -> [(k, a)] -> Map.Map k a
    • In the first argument of ‘foldl’, namely ‘foldfn’
      In the expression: foldl foldfn Map.empty
      In an equation for ‘fromListWith_’:
          fromListWith_ fn
            = foldl foldfn Map.empty
            where
                foldfn m (key, val) = Map.insertWith fn key val m
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try the suggested "possible fix" by the compiler? It looks like it should make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think everything is all right with your implementation - you need `ScopedTypeVariables` to work with the type of the inner function though:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

fromListWith_ :: forall a k. Ord k => (a -> a -> a) -> [(k, a)] -> Map.Map k a
fromListWith_ fn = foldl foldfn Map.empty
  where
    foldfn :: Map.Map k a -> (k, a) -> Map.Map k a
    foldfn m (key, val) = Map.insertWith fn key val m
```

---

Without those *scoped* variables the `a` in `foldfn :: (Map.Map k a) -> (k, a) -> Map.Map k a` is assumed to be different type-variable (a bit like *shadowing*) - same with `k` of course.

**Note:** to have this work you need the explicit `forall` there too!

---

if you don't like this just remove the signature:

```hs
fromListWith_ :: Ord k => (a -> a -> a) -> [(k, a)] -> Map.Map k a
fromListWith_ fn = foldl foldfn Map.empty
  where
    foldfn m (key, val) = Map.insertWith fn key val m
```

---

**PS:** you where missing a `Ord k` constraint too.

`insertWith` includes this constraint so you need to propagate it.

Comment: Thanks. I have added further details in response to your suggestion to remove the type signature from `foldfn`.

Comment: jup - that's the part from the **PS** ;)